# Docker access GCP artifacts through service account

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to access docker images in google artifact registry using a short lived Access Token.

I've got a client that has it's own Authentication/authorization against our API. The API has got access to a service account that has read capabilities to the images that the client is allowed to access.

What I am looking to do is to get an access token using the service account information, give that to a client that I authenticate etc.

The client can later use this token to sign into docker and access the containers for at long as the token is active.

The idea is that I don't want it to be long lived, I want to keep it in memory if possible.

I found [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token) for what I am looking for, though I am not getting it to work.

The backend (JS/TS) I imagine could do something like this:

```
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    credentials: {
      project_id: SERVICE_ACCOUNT.project_id,
      client_email: SERVICE_ACCOUNT.client_email,
      private_key: SERVICE_ACCOUNT.private_key,
    },
  });
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const targetClient = new Impersonated({
    sourceClient: client,
    targetPrincipal: OTHER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT.client_email,
    targetScopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  });
  const token = await targetClient.getAccessToken();
....
```

Then:

```
docker login europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin
```

No luck though. What am I doing wrong here? Not sure if the token is sufficient.

I've tried using an account with role/editor with the same uninformative response:

`GaxiosError: unable to impersonate: Error: invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-impersonation), there are multiple ways to impersonate a service account:

- Set the `--impersonate-service-account` flag or the `impersonate-service-account` property when running a Google Cloud CLI command. When you run a gcloud CLI command with this setting, gcloud CLI creates short-lived credentials for the service account, then runs the command with those credentials.

  You can also use the `--impersonate-service-account` flag when setting up your Application Default Credentials file. This setup enables client libraries that support impersonation to automatically impersonate the service account.
- Create short-lived credentials using the Service Account Credentials API, then use those credentials to authenticate an API request.

  Short-lived credentials have a limited lifetime, with durations of just a few hours or shorter, and are not automatically refreshed. They create less risk than long-lived credentials, such as service account keys.
- Use a credential configuration file to configure an external application to impersonate a service account. This option is only available for applications that use workload identity federation.

  When an application uses a credential configuration file to access Google Cloud, it first uses its environment-specific credentials to get a short-lived credential for a designated service account. Then, it uses that short-lived credential to authenticate to Google Cloud.

When you use the Google Cloud console, you always authenticate with your user credentials; you can't impersonate a service account to access resources in the Google Cloud console.

You can refer to the documentation and see if the error will still persist afterwards.